# How to implement image upload and serve field in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to implement an image uploader and server in my rest api which built with django-rest-framework.I'm using generic views right now but I couldnt combine those two.I will be grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to specify MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your setting:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#media-root

to add image upload image you can get and save image with this code:

```
    if file := request.data.get("file"):
        user = request.user
        user.photo = file
        user.save()
        return Response(status=201)
    raise NotAcceptable(detail=_("file is empty"))
```

to server image you need to return image url, and could be done with this:

```
user.photo.url
```

and this is how you should define datamodel

```
photo = models.ImageField(
    max_length=200, blank=True, null=True,
    upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "profile/",
)
```